# Linux - convert tab delimited to pipe delimited AND remove leading & trailing space

Tags: linux, shell, notepad++, delimiter, trim

I want to covert a flat data file to a new file based on below requirement:

> 1) Change tab delimited to pile delimited "|".
>
> 2) Remove any leading and trailing SPACE on each "column".
>
> 3) Some columns are NULL, I want to keep the null. e.g., A||B. (2nd column is null.)

**Example:**

Original file (test.dat) has a row of tab delimited data , 7 columns in total, **2 columns after "NY" are NULL**:

```
 A  New York    NY          Meal - Seafood       Grocery Department
```

Please be aware there are leading/trailing space on some fields:

```
(" A ", "Meal - Seafood   ", "  Grocery Department   ")
```

This is the final version I want in the new file:

```
A|New York|NY|||Meal - Seafood|Grocery Department
```

> Can any one write a sample code or shell script that I can use in Linux to ouput a new file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posix character class `[[:space:]]` and you can use `*` to match zero or more spaces. The literal `\t` matches a tab. Like,

```
$ sed "s/^[[:space:]]*//" test.dat | sed "s/[[:space:]]*\t[[:space:]]*/|/g" \
     | sed "s/[[:space:]]*$//" 
A|New York|NY|Meal - Seafood|Grocery Department   

$ cat test.dat
A   New York    NY   Meal - Seafood Grocery Department
```

Comment: Thanks!   I tried to use code   **sed 's/[[:space:]]*\t[[:space:]]*/|/g' test.dat > new.dat**,  the new output still have leading space on " A" and trailing space on "Grocery Dept  ".

Comment: You missed the first command then. Try it with what I posted, not part of it. I did add a third sed for the trailing space. But I have tested this.

Comment: Thanks! It worked..  Looks like your code above is 2 line,  I tried backspace to 1 line then it is not working.    How can I write to a new file that is similar to **sed 's/[[:space:]]*\t[[:space:]]*/|/g' test.dat > new.dat**?  Will this code work on this specific example only?

Comment: ignore my previous comment.   Here it worked to write to a new file,  **sed "s/^[[:space:]]*//" test.dat | sed "s/[[:space:]]*\t[[:space:]]*/|/g" | sed "s/[[:space:]]*$//" > new.dat**      My final question would be,  is this a "generic" code that can also work on other similar data based on the 2 requirement?

Comment: Those 2 requirements are pretty specific. But yes, for those two specific requirements this is "generic".

Comment: Elliott, I just realized I have another issue with the "generic" code, what if some columns are NULL, the code seems to skip those null, therefore the some columns are off position. I have changed my example data, would you be able to help take a look?

Comment: Change the middle command to `sed "s/ *\t */|/g"` then. And it won't consume extra tabs in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`.

Given:

```
$ cat -t file.tsv
 A ^INew York^INY^I^I^IMeal - Seafood   ^I  Grocery Department
```

(The tabs are showing as `^I`) there...)

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"; OFS="|"} 
     {for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) {
         gsub(/^[ ]+/,"",$i); gsub(/[ ]+$/,"",$i) 
        }
  } 1' file.tsv
A|New York|NY|||Meal - Seafood|Grocery Department
```